# Hide products from WooCommerce shop and archive pages if product author is not Admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is not related to who the current user is. What I'm trying to accomplish is to hide any products on the shop and archive pages if the product's author is Admin. I tried searching on here and other places, but anything I find is related to if the current user is logged in or is admin. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
function hide_product_by_user_role( $query ) {
    
    
     $authors = ( array ) $product->authors; // obtaining product author -- this is wrong
    
    
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() &&  $authors[0] != 'administrator' ) {
        
        .... what do I do here?
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_product_by_user_role' );
```

Comment: $query->set( 'author__not_in',  array($adminId)); may help you.

Comment: Keep in mind products are still accessable from anyone :) i would approach with product status over author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find the admin(s) id(s)
2. Include them in the `query`

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'hide_product_by_user_role', 999);

function hide_product_by_user_role($query){ 

    $users_args = array(
        'role__in' => array('Administrator'),
        'fields'   => 'ID'
    );

    $admins_ids = get_users($users_args);

    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() ) {
        $query->set('author__in', $admins_ids);
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#parameters

Comment: Thank you for the help! This worked, but I had to adjust the if statement from 'author_not__in to 'author__in' for it to work correctly.

Comment: You're welcome. I thought you were asking for the opposite. I'll update my answer.